# PDE $u_t-u_{xx}+x^2u+u^3=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ solution of the nonlinear heat equation
$$
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}(x,t)-\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}(x,t)
+x^2u(x,t)+(u(x,t))^3
\quad\forall(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty).
$$
Suppose that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(|u(x,t)|^2+\left|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x,t)\right|^2\right)dx
$$
is finite and continuous for all $t>0$. I want to prove that
$$
E(t):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} |u(x,t)|^2dx
$$
converges to $0$ as $t\to\infty$.

---

I derived the energy equation
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x,T)^2dx
  +\int_{T_0}^T\int_{\mathbb{R}}2(u_x^2+x^2u^2+u^4)dx dt
  =\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x,T_0)^2dx
\quad (0<T_0<T),
$$
so I know $E(t)$ is decreasing and converges to some value. I suspect
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]}u^2dx\le \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]}x^2u^2dx
$$
and
$$
 \left(\int_{-1}^1u^2dx\right)^2\le 2\int_{-1}^1u^4dx
$$
are usefull.

Comment: Have you considered using the integral form of Gronwall's inequality?

Comment: @Tulip Yes, but I think it is useless in this situation. How can I apply it?